# Word for strong negative stereotype

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word for something that has a very strong stereotype linked to it? Like for example if you were to say 'she has an std' you might immediately assume she had lots of unprotected sex and was quite wreckless, or someone having a large vocabulary being classed a nerd and a 'no-lifer'. I'm talking about that initial reaction, moreso negative than positive although any response would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: not sure if this is what you mean, but "negative connotation" and "negative association" and "negative implication" might do the job if you don't mind a two-word answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is what ***stigma*** is about.

From **[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stigma)**:

> **stigma**
>   *noun*
>
> : a set of negative and often unfair beliefs that a society or group
>   of people have about something
>
> There's a social stigma attached to receiving welfare.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about stereotyping, but a strong, reflexive, (typically) negative reaction is often referred to as a "visceral reaction".

Answer (score 0):

You may be referring to an instance of the halo effect, which is when a bias created in one area influences judgement in another. BTW, it is "reckless", not "wreckless", but I won't allow that to cause the halo effect to get to me.

Answer (score 0):

***Prejudice***  is what comes to mind:

> - an unfavorable opinion or feeling formed beforehand or without knowledge, thought, or reason.

(Dictionary.com)